# How to format complicated array with ._groupBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

My array looks like, but includes 1000+ objects:

```
    data = {
  0: {
    code: '3019476',
    _id: '60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e1',
    vendor: 'DKNY',
    tags: [
      { type: 1, label: 'dsfs' },
      { type: 2, label: 'thisOne' },
      { type: 3, label: 'sdas' },
    ],
  },
  1: {
    code: '3019475',
    _id: '60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e0',
    vendor: 'DKNY',
    tags: [
      { type: 1, label: 'sdfsd' },
      { type: 2, label: 'anotherOne' },
      { type: 3, label: 'sdfsd' },
    ],
  },
  2: {
    code: '3019474',
    _id: '60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e9',
    vendor: 'DKNY',
    tags: [
      { type: 1, label: 'gregf' },
      { type: 2, label: 'thisOne' },
      { type: 3, label: 'gregf' },
    ],
  },
};
```

I expect this as output:

```
0: {title: "thisOne", data: Array(2)"}
1: {title: "anotherOne", data: Array(1)"}
```

So I want to filter and count how many objects include different tag[1].label, saving full item data in 'data' inside result.

All my ideas failed, so I really need your help

Comment: `data` has a lot of syntax errors, try fixing them

Comment: Please include your failed ideas in the question. It helps people to answer your question and it helps you to learn more from it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are looking for [groupBy](https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) with a [property path](https://underscorejs.org/#property) [iteratee shorthand](https://underscorejs.org/#iteratee):

```js
import { groupBy } from 'underscore';

groupBy(data, ['tags', 1, 'label']);
// { thisOne: [Object, Object],
//   anotherOne: [Object]
// }
```

This produces an object with the labels as keys and the groups as values. From here, it is easy to get it in the exact shape of the example output from your question, for example using [chain](https://underscorejs.org/#chain) and [map](https://underscorejs.org/#map):

```js
import { chain } from 'underscore';

chain(data)
    .groupBy(['tags', 1, 'label'])
    .map((data, title) => ({data, title}))
    .value();
// [ { title: 'thisOne', data: [Object, Object] },
//   { title: 'anotherOne', data: [Object] }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of syntax error in data, fix them and it should work. See the code snippet below.

**NOTE:** Key/Value pairs in an object should separated with commas and `dsfs`, `thisOne` `sdas` should be valid variables or strings.

```js
data = {
  0: {
    code: '3019476',
    _id: '60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e1',
    vendor: 'DKNY',
    tags: [
      { type: 1, label: 'dsfs' },
      { type: 2, label: 'thisOne' },
      { type: 3, label: 'sdas' },
    ],
  },
  1: {
    code: '3019475',
    _id: '60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e0',
    vendor: 'DKNY',
    tags: [
      { type: 1, label: 'sdfsd' },
      { type: 2, label: 'anotherOne' },
      { type: 3, label: 'sdfsd' },
    ],
  },
  2: {
    code: '3019474',
    _id: '60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e9',
    vendor: 'DKNY',
    tags: [
      { type: 1, label: 'gregf' },
      { type: 2, label: 'thisOne' },
      { type: 3, label: 'gregf' },
    ],
  },
};

console.log(data[0].tags[1].label)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash for that. You can use plain javascript.

```js
const data= [
{code: "3019476", _id: "60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e1", vendor: "DKNY", tags: [{type: 1, label: 'dsfs'},{type: 2, label: 'thisOne'},{type: 3, label: 'sdas'}]}, {code: "3019475", _id: "60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e0", vendor: "DKNY", tags: [{type: 1, label: 'sdfsd'},{type: 2, label: 'anotherOne'},{type: 3, label: 'sdfsd'}]}, {code: "3019474", _id: "60033f61-8a4e-4622-9731-decd07bc44e9", vendor: "DKNY", tags: [{type: 1, label: 'gregf'},{type: 2, label: 'thisOne'},{type: 3, label: 'gregf'}]}]

const newData = data.map(d => { 
  let result = {};
  result.title = d.tags.find(tag => tag.type === 2).label;
  result.data = d.tags.filter(tag => tag.type === 2); 
  return result;
});

console.log(newData);
```

P.S.: This snippet is considering that more than one tagType can be included into the data array and that the first found will be used as title.
If that is not what you want then the question should be clearer.

Comment: "You don't need library X, you can use plain JavaScript" is *always* true if library X itself is written in plain JavaScript. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use library X; libraries save work so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, but in that case you are not reinventing the wheel when there is already a wheel to be used. When the library is not supported anymore, javascript will be. 
But I understand your point and I agree that he asked for a use with the library. Thanks! I will consider this in my future answers.